# Find person referring to my website

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

If someone sends my website link to another in facebook and that user visits my page using that link

Is there a way to find the person who sent him that link?

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional parameter with your link and using that parameter you can detect who referred that link to the other person.

For example original link:

```
home/xyx/play.php?gameId=10
```

modified link with refId=10

```
home/xyx/play.php?gameId=10&refId=10
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he is asking for, read the question again.

Comment: "Is there a way to find the person who sent him that link"... isn't it the 'person' is 'someone' in "If someone sends my website link"?

Answer (score 0):

The first answer might work (if the link is shared keeping the "refid" parameter, yet you can't be sure it will be kept).

The answer I would provide is to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` which contains the referer site (so you just check if there's a match between $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] and facebook.com using string comparison functions or even regular expressions if you need a higher precision), yet as [**PHP states**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

So even this method might not work at all, my suggestion is to use both (reference parameter and http_referer) to achieve higher possibilities.